# SignalR object is listening by Observer but when trying set Editext, it is null

Tags: android, service, signalr, observer-pattern

I'm trying to use Signalr with service class to control signalr connections. When connection is on, Observable works fine and fire observer from main activity:

```
    mHubProxy.on("onConnected",
            new SubscriptionHandler1<MessageReceived>() {
                @Override
                public void run(final MessageReceived msg) {
                    mHandler.post( new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                            calendar.getTime();
                            Log.i("script","onConnected: " + calendar.getTime()+ " context: "  + getApplicationContext());
                            observableTask.setMessageReceived(msg);
                        }
                    } );
                }
            }
            , MessageReceived.class);
```

Return to main Activity that I started Service this way:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClass(mContext, RealTime.class);
   bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

It receives model class in Observer (update) but when It tries to txtChatMessage.setText(), it's is null !

```
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
    messageReceived = (ObservableTask) observable;
    try {
        txtChatMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtChatMessage);
        txtChatMessage.setText(messageReceived.getMessageReceived().Sender);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.getTime();
        Log.i("script", "update runOnUiThread: " + calendar.getTime() + " context: ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String error = e.getMessage();
        Log.i("script", "update Exception: " + error);
    }
}
```

I try main thread, UI thread and other ways but all view components are null. When I use just signalr without service and observer works fine. So, anyone can help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue, it was observer, just changed to BroadcastReceiver !!